# Access VBA, making a field appear when combobox value is selected

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to make a `listbox` appear when a value in a `combobox` is selected. I put in this code:

```
Private Sub categoriebox_AfterUpdate()

    If categoriebox.Value = "MON" Then
        Me.monstertype.Visible = True
    Else: Me.monstertype.Visible = False

    End If

End Sub
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> Run time error 13: type mismatch

The `combobox` selection is taken from a table. The fields in this table are `ID`, `category`, and `description`. The value I need is from category: MON, short for Monster but since this is selected in the `combobox` in the same form do I still need to define this?

I also tried using `ID = 14` but this also did not work.

Comment: you don't need to write any code for the combobox. You need your rowsource to have sql: select category from yourtableName.

Comment: In your immediate window (`Ctrl+G`) type `MsgBox Form.("YourFormName").Controls("categoriebox") ` and press enter and see what it says.  (Make sure you have the `Mon` dropdown option selected).  This should give you an idea what you should be comparing to.

Answer (score 0):

You're code is correct.

However, the combo box value is set to the bound column number, you probably have selected multiple columns on the row source property of the combo box. This will compare the ID number with the text "MON" - resulting in a type mismatch.

Answer: Either select only the category as row source or select a different bound column number.

e.g.

ID || category || description

Set combo box bound column property to 2. Now the value of the combobox is the contents of category column.